# Can't reset XY coordinates of textview after leaving OnTouchListener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to reset the coordinates back to the original position, but what I think should do it, doesn't seem to be working the way I think it should.
Here is the important code:

```
num1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        startX = num1.getX(); // num1 is a TextView
        startY = num1.getY(); // here I am trying to get the original coordinates

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = event.getRawX();
                y = event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = event.getRawX();
                y = event.getRawY();
                num1.setX(x - 100);
                num1.setY(y - 250); // "y - 250" keeps the textview under finger
                apple1.setX(x - 100);
                apple1.setY(y - 250);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (((num1.getX() >= basket1.getX()) && (num1.getX() < basket2.getX())) && (event.getRawY() > linearLayout.getY())) {
                    basket1Num = String.valueOf(num1.getText());
                    basket1Text.setText(basket1Num);
                } else if (((num1.getX() >= basket2.getX()) && (num1.getX() > basket1.getX())) && (event.getRawY() > linearLayout2.getY())) {
                    basket2Num = String.valueOf(num1.getText());
                    basket2Text.setText(basket2Num);
                } else {
                    num1.setX(startX); // if the user has moved it somewhere other than the basket the TextView should go back.
                    num1.setY(startY);
                }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

So basically num1 is a TextView, above the switch I am trying to get the starting position. If the user does not place the TextView into the basket image I would like it to go back to its original position. I though gathering the starting xy position and telling the app to set it back to those positions would do it but it has zero effect. Any help would be great.

Thank you!

EDIT: Apple1 is the ImageView that follows Num1 TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the touch event is fired, you are setting the start coordinates. That means that as you drag, you are resetting the coordinates to its current location. It loses the state of what the start coordinates were.

What you probably meant to do, is when you start dragging, you set the start coordinates. In the example below, I just moved where you set the starting coordinates into `ACTION_DOWN`. That is fired once when you press down.

```
num1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = num1.getX(); // num1 is a TextView
                startY = num1.getY(); // here I am trying to get the original coordinates

                x = event.getRawX();
                y = event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = event.getRawX();
                y = event.getRawY();
                num1.setX(x - 100);
                num1.setY(y - 250); // "y - 250" keeps the textview under finger
                apple1.setX(x - 100);
                apple1.setY(y - 250);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (((num1.getX() >= basket1.getX()) && (num1.getX() < basket2.getX())) && (event.getRawY() > linearLayout.getY())) {
                    basket1Num = String.valueOf(num1.getText());
                    basket1Text.setText(basket1Num);
                } else if (((num1.getX() >= basket2.getX()) && (num1.getX() > basket1.getX())) && (event.getRawY() > linearLayout2.getY())) {
                    basket2Num = String.valueOf(num1.getText());
                    basket2Text.setText(basket2Num);
                } else {
                    num1.setX(startX); // if the user has moved it somewhere other than the basket the TextView should go back.
                    num1.setY(startY);
                }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh that was stupid of me, I assumed everytime they had their finger/mouse on it it would fire ACTION_DOWN, thank you so much!